# jQuery - tag to get image from service is ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, service

I have a block of Javascript code that gets an array of strings, and for each string, it is to put an image into a table cell.

```
var TableString = "<table><tr>";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetItemNames", "DataHandler.svc")',
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        for (var N in data) {
            TableString += ("<td><img=/DataHandler.svc/RotateString?theString=" + data[N] + " /></td>");
        }
    },
    error: function (HelpRequest, ErrorCode, TheError) {
        TableString += "<td>Error: " + TheError + "</td>";
    },
    async: false
});
TableString += "</tr></table>";
$(graphics_div).html(TableString);
```

GetItemNames returns an array of strings in data, and each data item generates an  tag with a call to the service to get a dynamic image.  The method that generates the image works, and the strings in data are what I expect them to be; however, while the table is generated and displayed, the images themselves are not appearing, because the RotateString method is never actually called.

How do I get the page to call the RotateString handler for each string and generate (and display) the corresponding images in this case?

Comment: `<img=...` is invalid HTML for sure. Try `<img src="...">`.

Comment: d'oh - that fixed it